# Evaluation points following a bivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a function of two variables, say $f(a, b)$, which I want to evaluate (and later average) in the neighborhood of $a=0$ and $b=0$, with density of points around $(a,\,b)$ following a Gaussian distribution.

Taking the example of the first variable $a$, the largest number of points should be at $a = 0$ (peak of the Gaussian distribution) and then on both sides of the $a$-axis the density of the points should decrease according to a Gaussian distribution.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Look for `NormalDistribution[\[Mu],\[Sigma]] `

Comment: What exactly follows a Gaussian distribution?  Do you have a nonlinear regression with $y=f(a,b) + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ or do you have errors in the predictor variables $y=f(a+\epsilon_a, b+\epsilon_b)$ where $(\epsilon_a,\epsilon_b)$ follows a bivariate Gaussian distribution?

Comment: If the objective is to describe the distribution of $f$ (pdf, mean, variance, etc.) given that $(a,b)$ has a bivariate Gaussian distribution, have you tried `TransformedDistribution` ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
dist = MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[2]]
pts = RandomVariate[dist, 500];
Graphics[Point[pts], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

You may chose a different variance `var` by e.g.:

```
dist = MultinormalDistribution[ var IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working  but Gaussian distribution is always defined by HWFM/FWHM. How can I input it in the format you suggested.

Comment: HWFM - Half width at full maxima. Another way to define the width of a peak in some functions, but FWHM is enough. As you said, "var" is the 4Log(2/FWHM^2). Can you suggest any reference for it. Just trying to understand "MultinormalDistribution" better. Description given on Mathematica is too complicated and does not talk about FWHM. Thanks

Comment: In your case you have a diagonal correlation matrix. That means the distribution is rotational symmetric. If you take a cut along the x-axis you get a simple 1 dim Gaussian. Then google  "Gaussian"  and e.g. the Wiki will give you the necessary information.